# PHP, MySQL, PDO Transactions - Does the code inside try block stop at commit()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I'm pretty new to transactions.

Before, what I was doing was something like:

*Code Block 1*

```
$db = new PDO(...);

$stmt = $db->prepare(...);

if($stmt->execute()){
    // success
    return true;
}else{
    // failed
    return false;
}
```

But in an attempt to group multiple queries into a single transaction, I'm now using something like:

*Code Block 2*

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$db->beginTransaction();

try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare(... 1 ...);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $db->prepare(... 2 ...);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $db->prepare(... 3 ...);
    $stmt->execute();

    $db->commit();

    return true;
}catch(Exception $e){
    // Failed, maybe write the error to a txt file or something
    $db->rollBack();
    return false;
}
```

My question is: If the transaction fails for whatever reason, does the code stop at `$db->commit();` and jump to the `catch` block? Or would the `return true;` run first, and then it would try to go to the `catch`? 'Cause if that's the case, then I've already returned, and so it wouldn't go to the `catch`. AND it would have returned the wrong value.

Do I still need to include something like:

*Code Block 3*

```
if($stmt->commit()){
    return true;
}
```

or is it sufficient the way I have it written in *Code Block 2*?

Comment: Yes, if the code stop at `$db->commit();` then output of `catch` block will be returned so you don't need to add a condition like `if($stmt->commit()) ....` http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the transaction fails for whatever reason, the code does stop **at the very line where error occurred** end then the execution jumps directly to the catch block. So it is sufficient the way you have it written in Code Block 2.

Note that you should **always re-throw the Exception after rollback.** Otherwise you will never have an idea what was a problem. So it should be

```
try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare(... 1 ...);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $db->prepare(... 2 ...);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $db->prepare(... 3 ...);
    $stmt->execute();

    $db->commit();

    return true;
}catch(Exception $e){
    $db->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: What does the `throw $e;` do exactly? Can't I just access the exception via `$e->getMessage()`?

Comment: You can but you shouldn't. Exceptions are not supposed to be handled right in place. It's programming. You are supposed to write the handling code only once, not writing it every time you run a query. Besides, what if you will change your mind some day, and will have another idea to process the error other than logging? Will set for the mass rewriting?

Comment: Besides, speaking of this particular case, PHP can log errors for you already. Means, in case you need to log, you don't have to write a single line, save for `ini_set('log_errors', 1);` one

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Just found [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) article, which discusses much of what you just said. Wouldn't be surprised if you'd written it yourself. You got the steal though!

Comment: Yep, it was me. I wrote it mainly because there are so many bad examples around, teaching people to handle exceptions wrong way. Glad you liked it!

Comment: My knowledge is far less than what you think. To be called a god one needs to know ten times more. Speaking of myself I am just obsessed with sharing knowledge, sort of addict for SO.

Comment: I've got a doozy of a transactions question over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355063/php-mysql-pdo-transactions-order-of-operations-within-a-pdo-transaction), if you have a moment to take a quick peak. Order of operations stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The execution is stopped when an exception is thrown.

The first return will not be reached but the catch statement will be executed.

You can even return the commit directly:

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
try {
    // insert/update query
    return $dbh->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     $dbh->rollBack();
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you face any error you can do this to rollback all transactions like this

```
catch(Exception $e){
    $db->rollBack();
    // Failed, maybe write the error to a txt file or something
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Amit, thanks. I forgot to put that line in the question, but it is in my code. But your answer doesn't address my question. The rollback isn't my concern, but rather any code that might exist beyond the `$stmt->commit();` line.

Comment: If any of your transaction code fails it goes to your catch block. Whatever code is inside catch block will be executed.