# PHP, MySQL, PDO Transactions - Can fetchAll() come before commit()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

More transaction questions!

What I have right now is a mess of strung-together queries, that are all manually reversed if any fail:

*Code Block 1*

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare(...); // Update table1, set col=col+1
if($stmt1 = $db->execute(...)){

    $stmt2 = $db->prepare(...); // Insert into table2, id=12345
    if($stmt2 = $db->execute(...)){

        $stmt3 = $db->prepare(...); // Select val from table3
        if($stmt3 = $db->execute(...)){

            $result = $stmt3->fetchAll();
            if($result[0]['val'] == something){

                $stmt4 = $db->prepare(...); // Update table4, set status=2
                if($stmt4 = $db->execute(...)){

                    return true;

                }else{
                    $stmt1 = $db->prepare(...); // Update table1, set col=col-1 (opposite of above)
                    $stmt1 = $db->execute(...);

                    $stmt2 = $db->prepare(...); // Delete from table2, where id=12345 (opposite of above)
                    $stmt2 = $db->execute(...);

                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }else{
            $stmt1 = $db->prepare(...); // Update table1, set col=col-1 (opposite of above)
            $stmt1 = $db->execute(...);

            $stmt2 = $db->prepare(...); // Delete from table2, where id=12345 (opposite of above)
            $stmt2 = $db->execute(...);

            return false;
        }
    }else{
        $stmt1 = $db->prepare(...); // Update table1, set col=col-1 (opposite of above)
        $stmt1 = $db->execute(...);

        return false;
    }
}
```

It's a mess, difficult to debug, difficult to add on to, difficult to understand when the queries are large, and won't return all tables back to original state if the connection is lost mid-way through.

This same process is even worse when deleting a row, because everything in it needs to be stored - just in case the operation needs to be undone.

Now, I know *most* of this will still work when I port it over to a single transaction, but the one part I am unsure of is:

*Code Block 2*

```
$result = $stmt3->fetchAll();
if($result[0]['val'] == something){
    ... continue ...
}else{
    ... reverse operations ...
    return false;
}
```

Because the results-gathering would take place before the `commit()` in the transaction. As follows:

*Code Block 3*

```
$db->beginTransaction();    

try{
    $stmt1 = $db->prepare(...);
    $stmt1->execute();

    $stmt2 = $db->prepare(...);
    $stmt2->execute();

    $stmt3 = $db->prepare(...);
    $stmt3->execute();

    $result = $stmt3->fetchAll();
    if($result[0]['val'] == something){
        $stmt4 = $db->prepare(...);
        $stmt4->execute();
    }else{
        $db->rollBack();
        return false;
    }

    $db->commit();

    return true;
}catch(Exception $e){
    $db->rollBack();
    throw $e;
    return false;
}
```

Will this work? Specifically, can I include the `$result = $stmt3->fetchAll();` *before* the `commit()`, and then execute the conditional query?

Also, I'm not entirely sure on this, but do I require the `$db->rollBack();` within the `try` block, if the code is exited (`return false`) before the `commit()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your first question:

> Specifically, can I include the $result = $stmt3->fetchAll(); before the commit(), and then execute the conditional query?

I see no reason why it should not work. A transaction behaves basically the same as operations without transactions - except that changes are only drafts. Any changes you make in the previous statements will be applied to a "working copy" valid for this single session only. For you it will appear completely transparent. However any changes will be rolled back if you do not commit them.

Also worth noting (emphasis mine):

> In layman's terms, any work carried out in a transaction, even if it is carried out in stages, is guaranteed to be applied to the database safely, and **without interference from other connections**, when it is committed.

This can cause racing conditions.

## Your second question:

> Also, I'm not entirely sure on this, but do I require the $db->rollBack(); within the try block, if the code is exited (return false) before the commit()?

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php) it says:

> When the script ends or when a connection is about to be closed, if you have an outstanding transaction, PDO will automatically roll it back.

Therefore you do not necessarily require to roll back manually as it will be done by the driver itself.

However note the following from the same source as well:

> Warning PDO only checks for transaction capabilities on driver level. If certain runtime conditions mean that transactions are unavailable, PDO::beginTransaction() will still return TRUE without error if the database server accepts the request to start a transaction.

So be sure to check the compatibility beforehand!

## A few notes

Do NOT begin a transaction in another transaction. This will commit the first transaction implicitely. See [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php#109753).

Another note from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php):

> Some databases, including MySQL, automatically issue an implicit COMMIT when a database definition language (DDL) statement such as DROP TABLE or CREATE TABLE is issued within a transaction. The implicit COMMIT will prevent you from rolling back any other changes within the transaction boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. So could it be said that I'd be safer/better off to leave the `rollBack()` in the failed condition, to guarantee the rollback happens? Also, just to double check, your last point about nested transactions is just a warning - I didn't do that in *Code Block 3* did I?

Comment: 1) I would recommend you to include the manual roll back because it is easier to read. It's always nice to know the documentation by heart but reading in the code what you're are trying to attempt is always preferable.

2) The notes shall be considered as warnings. The documentation is a bit ... bad at pointing that stuff out and I ran into strange errors before I read that comment.

Comment: To be more precise about the implicit commit: I happened to call several independent functions in a row which all had to call beginTransaction() (because they could all be called standalone as well). Each time a beginTransaction() is called the previous transaction is committed. I feel that the best approach is to build a wrapper class which keeps track of how many transactions are started and commits only if all were successfully committed (a simple counter suits).

Comment: Yalon, with regards to your last point (nested transactions) - that only applies to to transactions within the same database, right? I have two different databases, `$dbu` and `$dbb`. Can I do something like `$dbu->beginTransaction(); try{$dbb->beginTransaction(); try{}catch{}}catch{}` because they aren't acting on the same PDO object?

Comment: Yes. The transaction only applies to the very session it was started with. So if you open two distinct sessions simultaneously they have two distinct transactions which do not interfere with each other.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Continuing on the same subject (nested-but-separate transactions), I've got another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363417/php-mysql-pdo-transaction-can-rollback-be-used-after-commit-has-been-cal) if you have the time to take a peak.