# PHP, MySQL, PDO Transaction - Can rollBack() be used after commit() has been called?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I've looked through resources for [`rollBack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php), [`commit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) and [various transaction stuff](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), but I cannot find whether `rollBack()` can be called after `commit()` has already been called.

The situation is this:

I have two different databases: `$dbu = new PDO(..db1..)` and `$dbb = new PDO(..db2..)`

Both databases have tables that are being updated within a single function. The operation is *all or none* - either all tables are successfully updated, or none are.

Using two separate transactions, if the transaction for `$dbu` is successfully completed, but the transaction for `$dbb` fails, I have to undo what was done in the first transaction:

*Code Block 1*

```
$dbu->beginTransaction();
try{
    $stmt = $dbu->prepare(...);
    $stmt->execute();

    // stuff

    $dbu->commit();
}catch(Exception $e){
    // do stuff

    $dbu->rollBack();
    exit();
}

$dbb->beginTransaction();
try{
    $stmt = $dbb->prepare(...);
    $stmt->execute();

    // stuff

    $dbb->commit();
}catch(Exception $e){
    // do stuff

    $dbb->rollBack();

    // Need to undo what we did
    $dbu->beginTransaction();
    try{
        $stmt = $dbu->prepare(...);
        $stmt->execute();

        // opposite of whatever operation was in the first transaction

        $dbu->commit();
    }catch(Exception $e){
    }

    exit();
}
```

This is messy, and unreliable if something happens to the connection in between the two primary transactions.

So what I'd like to do instead is nest the second transaction within the first. It seems logical that I'd be able to do this, because `$dbu` and `$dbb` are two unique PDO objects, that point to two separate databases. It looks like:

*Code Block 2*

```
$dbu->beginTransaction();
try{
    $stmt = $dbu->prepare(...);
    $stmt->execute();

    // stuff

    $dbb->beginTransaction();
    try{
        $stmt = $dbb->prepare(...);
        $stmt->execute();

        // stuff

        $dbb->commit();
    }catch(Exception $e){
        // do stuff

        $dbb->rollBack();
        $dbu->rollBack(); // Since $dbu was first part of transaction, it needs to be rolled back too
        exit();
    }

    $dbu->commit();
}catch(Exception $e){
    // do stuff

    $dbu->rollBack();
    $dbb->rollBack(); // **THIS IS THE TRICKY LINE!**
    exit();
}
```

Since `commit()` for `$dbu` is called *after* the entire `$dbb` transaction, the case may arise where `$dbb` was successful, and `$dbu` failed. If that happens, I need to undo what was done in the `$dbb` transaction.

**So...**

Can I call `$dbb->rollBack();` (near the end of *Code Block 2*) **AFTER** `$dbb->commit();` has run? Or am I stuck in the same situation as I initially was, where I have to manually reverse whatever happened in the `$dbb` transaction? Again, this isn't ideal. If the connection drops in the middle of this, I could be left with data in the `$dbb` tables that shouldn't be there (because the `$dbu` transaction failed).

Perhaps I can combine the two transactions into a single `try/catch` block?

*Code Block 3*

```
$dbu->beginTransaction();
$dbb->beginTransaction();

try{
    $stmt = $dbu->prepare(...);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt2 = $dbb->prepare(...);
    $stmt2->execute();

    // stuff

    $dbu->commit();
    $dbb->commit();
}catch(Exception $e){
    // do stuff

    $dbu->rollBack();
    $dbb->rollBack(); // **THIS IS THE TRICKY LINE!**
    exit();
}
```

But this doesn't look a whole lot different than *Code Block 2*, because we can still have the situation where `$dbu->commit();` is successful, but `$dbb->commit();` fails. If that happens, then we are still trying to call `$dbu->rollBack();` after its partner commit has already been processed.

If I *cannot* call `rollBack()` after `commit()`, is there a commonly used method to tackle this 2-DB problem? Something that is as efficient as `rollBack()` and doesn't require an entire extra transaction to undo the former operation.

**EDIT 1**

Adding on to *Code Block 3*, could I verify each execution as they are called?

*Code Block 4*

```
$dbu->beginTransaction();
$dbb->beginTransaction();

try{
    $stmt = $dbu->prepare(...);
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        throw new Exeption('something somethign');
    }

    $stmt2 = $dbb->prepare(...);
    if(!$stmt2->execute()){
        throw new Exeption('something two');
    }

    // stuff

    $dbu->commit();
    $dbb->commit();
}catch(PDOException $e){
    // do stuff

    $dbu->rollBack();
    $dbb->rollBack(); // **THIS IS THE TRICKY LINE!**
    exit();
}catch(Exception $e){
    // do stuff

    $dbu->rollBack();
    $dbb->rollBack(); // **THIS IS THE TRICKY LINE!**
    exit();
}
```

Will this help ensure the two `commit` statements have the best possible chance of succeeding? Or does the `try/catch` block automatically throw `PDOException` before the custom ones are ever called? It would be nice to have a simple identifier to know which transaction is failing, opposed to the entire `$e->getMessage();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot roll back committed changes.

As with your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355063/php-mysql-pdo-transactions-can-fetchall-come-before-commit/37355643) code block 3 is the way to go. Even though a commit might fail it will not fail because of common errors (like wrong syntax or constraint violation or what else). Hypothetical the whole PHP process might be killed right in between both commits resetting the latter letting you with no chance to fix the resulting errors in-code. However you will have to take care of those rare exceptions separately (e.g. backups) because I don't see an efficient way to handle them in-code.

Also remember that when committing the changes have already been applied but not been "published". So the commit itself is rarely to fail (only for exceptional reasons).

**@EDIT 1**

The way you handle errors depends on how you set up your PDO instances. See the [documentation on how errors can be handled by PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

Your code block 4 will work if you use the default mode (not setting the error mode explicitely or setting it to `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense with the "commit itself is rarely to fail," since all the leg-work has been done by that point. I've added an edit to the end of the question, with a couple thoughts to help mitigate issues, if you could let me know your thoughts, if it's even worth adding.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yeah, I have it set to `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`, so I reckon it won't even see my custom exceptions.

Comment: If you set the error mode to throw exceptions you will have to surround each `prepare`/`execute` statement with their own `try`/`catch` block in order to distinguish between them - which you probably have guessed.

Comment: What happens if I run a query, with the above attribute (i.e. `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`), but no `try/catch` blocks? I assume I only run into an issue if the query fails?

Comment: Yes. As soon as there is an error (e.g. query fails) it will throw an exception. If there is no surrounding `try`/`catch` anywhere in the call stack there are two possibilities: Either you have an exception handler installed (http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) in which case the uncaught exception is passed to the handler or PHP dies with an "Uncaught Exception ..." error which will immediatly stop the execution (I'm not sure whether destructors & co are called...). See http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php for more information.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to have a proper transaction across different database connections.

Although you can do some awkward workarounds, it won't have your transaction a real one.

So, you have to either keep all the operations within a single database or forget about transactions

Comment: What I think I'm going to do is keep it the same as *Code Block 3/4* and have a script run on a cron job periodically (even once a day is more than enough) that compares all the tables, and removes any miss-matches due to bad. Just spent a couple days switching more than 1000 queries over to grouped transactions like the ones above, so it's gonna stay like this for a bit. Maybe we will have to change the schema and layouts in the future, or opt for a different database altogether.

Comment: @Birrel When you think of a different way you should defenitely take a look at the CAP-Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) as I think this is connected to what Your Common Sense wanted to point out.

Comment: Can you share those "awkward workarounds"?